# Dynamic rows grid. Position element is not initiating

Tags: magento2, dynamic-rows

Continuously appearing problem with the position element of the dynamic rows component if we wanna use drag&drop feature. For reference I use a Related Products rows grid at the Product edit form. In that js configuration a position field has `visible = false` property but nevertheless it is initiating properly  via `registry.async()` in `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/dynamic-rows/record.js` file function.

I spent a lot of hours trying find out why is my position element is not initiating but with no results.
Has anyone also faced with this annoying issue?

---

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Correct behavior]

But in my case I've got this:

[image: Incorrect behavior]

Answer (score 0):

After a lots of researching I finally found out a reason why it happens.

The main problem is a layout difference. In my case I have Tabs layout unlike the Product edit page where we have 1 column (generic) layout.
For the Generic layout configuration processing Magento uses class `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generic` and `addChildren` method which responsible for collecting all children components respectively.

But for the Tabs layout Magento uses an another class `\Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs` with redefined `addChildren` fucntion. We should look into one interesting method in that class - `prepareChildComponents`. It renders all children components and checking for their visibility:

```
$isVisible = $child->getData('config/visible');
if ($isVisible !== null && $isVisible == 0) {
    continue;
}
```

If the child component is invisible it's not rendering at all and not adding as a child to the  component. That's why `position` field disappears from the html and Drag&Drop functionality didn't work properly.

I decided to rewrite this class and its method simultaneously. I created `adminhtml/di.xml` file with the next configuration:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs" type="MyNameSpace\MyModule\Component\Layout\Tabs" />
```

And created `MyNameSpace\MyModule\Component\Layout\Tabs` respectively where I added method to check for the dynamic rows record component:

```
namespace MyNameSpace\MyModule\Component\Layout;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;

class Tabs extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs
{
    /**
     * @param $component
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isDynamicRowsRecordComponent($component)
    {
        return $component->getConfig('component') == 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record';
    }

    /**
     * @param UiComponentInterface $component
     * @param string $parentName
     * @return array
     */
    protected function prepareChildComponents(UiComponentInterface $component, $parentName)
    {
        $name = $component->getName();
        $childComponents = $component->getChildComponents();

        $childrenStructure = [];
        foreach ($childComponents as $childName => $child) {
            $isVisible = $child->getData('config/visible');
            if ($isVisible !== null && $isVisible == 0 && !$this->isDynamicRowsRecordComponent($component)) {
                continue;
            }
            /**
             * @var UiComponentInterface $childComponent
             * @var array $childStructure
             */
            list($childComponent, $childStructure) = $this->prepareChildComponents($child, $component->getName());
            $childrenStructure = array_merge($childrenStructure, $childStructure);
            $component->addComponent($childName, $childComponent);
        }

        $structure = [
            $name => [
                'type' => $component->getComponentName(),
                'name' => $component->getName(),
                'children' => $childrenStructure
            ]
        ];

        list($config, $dataScope) = $this->prepareConfig((array) $component->getConfiguration(), $name, $parentName);

        if ($dataScope !== false) {
            $structure[$name]['dataScope'] = $dataScope;
        }
        $structure[$name]['config'] = $config;

        return [$component, $structure];
    }
}
```

Now it works as it should. Hope it helps anyone!